# How to keep looping until non-integer is entered

Tags: c++, loops

I have this program where I am trying to keep looping until something that is entered is a non-integer. No matter if I enter a non-integer or an integer the program still breaks and end. Please help

```
int data;
do
{
    cout<<"enter data: ";
    cin>>data;
    cout<<"yes"<<endl;
    return data;
} while(cin.good());
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `return` (or write it after the while) it break your code before the while line...

Answer (score 0):

This simple code snippet should work just fine.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int data;
    while(std::cin >> data)
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are defining data as integer you just have to check is cin 
When cin gets input it can't use, it sets failbit:

```
int data 
while(true)
{
    cout<<"enter data: ";
    cin>>data;   
    if(!cin) // or if(cin.fail())
    {
        // user didn't input a number
        break;
    }
     cout<<"yes"<<endl;
 }
```